# Keep me logged in with cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a login SESSION but I need a keep me logged in check box made with cookie so if the cookie is already set I need  my script to enter to index. This is my error on browser " This webpage has a redirect loop"
Here is my code

```
session_start();
if (isset($_COOKIE['user']) && isset($_COOKIE['p']) ){
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
}
if ($_SESSION['login']!="success" ){
header("location: login.php");
}


<body>
Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?>
<br>
<a href="logout.php">LogOut</a>
</body>
```

Comment: So users who share cookies with others could access each other's account? This could also be done maliciously. There's a lot more to 'keep logged in' than perhaps you realise. There are millions of security articles about this

Comment: The 'This webpage has a redirect loop' error means that a page is redirecting to itself. For instance, your 'login.php' might be referring to 'login.php' again, and again, and again... and never finish unless the browser intervenes.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Software I know, I need something like if cookies is set skip to index. can you help me?

Comment: That will not help you. I assume, but you don't say, that the piece of code in your example is the 'login.php' file? Hence the loop. However you create the loop when the login is not successful. In other words, this is what you want to do: When the login is not successful do NOT go to the login page but skip to the index page. This would make logging in impossible. I guess you have to rethink this completely. Check out examples of login systems: http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-stickies-167/program-basic-secure-login-system-using-php-mysql-891201.html

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is actually fairly easy to locate:

```
if ($_SESSION['login']!="success" ){
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

If your `$_SESSION` value `login` does not contain "success", you redirect back to your page. That value still won't exist, so the redirect happens again. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Further, the code before:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['user']) && isset($_COOKIE['p']) ){
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
}
```

Seems to be making sure you *don't* have the SESSION value, when you should.

---

That solves the specific issue you were having here, but I have to say I really don't know what you're trying to do. There's no code that sets the values in the session or cookies, so... I can tell you that storing username and password in a cookie is a Really Bad Idea ™. You may want to just look for a user authentication framework, instead.

Answer (score 1):

set your time for cookie

```
setcookie("user", "Test", time()+3600);
```

Cookie is not safe, you can use SESSION

And remember not to clear cookies while you are in the page

Hope this helps you

Comment: I have a cookie set in my login page. This is my index and I need if the cookie is set to skip over the session and go to index

Comment: Do you want to make a "keep me logged in checkbox"?

Comment: Yes and I need in my index page to have a cookie who remember my session. My cookie is set in login page and if the cookie is set my login page redirect to index.